# Webservice requiring timestamp of request - Smart way to get accurate time?

Tags: web-services

I am consuming a webservice in my mobile app which requires hashing, among other information, a timestamp of when the request was generated. If the time is out by a few minutes then my requests fail.

Since I cannot rely on my users having correct time on their devices I have changed the app to first make a request to my server for the current time, then make the actual request to the webservice. This works but seems messy. Am I approaching this in the wrong way? Is there a common way of solving this issue?

Comment: Does the app expect users to have internet?

Comment: Yes. It is a requirement

Comment: In that case use your website, because its a timeout question let (for example) time.yoursite.net generate a xml o.s.s. You can ask for a timestamp and use your server time as a reference point.

Comment: What is an OSS? I am asking my server for a timestamp, my question was is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this. It seems long to have to make 2 requests to complete 1 (that is - goto my server to get the time, then goto target server to perform the actual request)

Comment: o.s.s. = or something similar :-) Hmm, I see your point, but you need some reference point, isn't it possible to add the time in the first call?

Comment: Ah! I see. You mean when logging into the application return a timestamp? It is possible, it just means if more time has passed than is allowed before having the timestamp invalidated then I would just have to perform another request for the time from my server, before sending off the target request.